# Change File Extension on Multiple Files

Tags: vb.net

I have some file in a folder.

> D:\Text\Text.FL
>   D:\Text\Text1.FL
>   D:\Text\Text2.FL

i want to rename extension "**.FL**" to "**.txt**"
I've tried with this code

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("D:\Text\Text.fl","Text.txt")
```

but I want to shorten that code

Answer (score 2):

You want to shorten one line of code?  You can call `File.Move` if you import the `System.IO` namespace but you would need to pass two full paths in that case.  Maybe what you actually mean is that you don't want to have to write out a line like that for each file.  If you want to change all ".fl" files to ".txt" in a folder then this is what I would do:

```
For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.fl")
    File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".txt"))
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

An example usage of my file renamer method below:

```
Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Directory")

dInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.FL", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList.
    ForEach(Sub(fInfo As FileInfo)
                RenameFile(fInfo.FullName, fInfo.Name, ".txt")
            End Sub)
```

With this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Renames a file.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sourceFile">The source file.</param>
''' <param name="targetFileName">The target file name.</param>
''' <param name="targetFileExt">The target file ext.</param>
''' <exception cref="IO.FileNotFoundException">File not found.</exception>
Public Shared Sub RenameFile(ByVal sourceFile As FileInfo,
                             ByVal targetFileName As String,
                             Optional ByVal targetFileExt As String = "")

    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFileExt) Then
            targetFileExt = sourceFile.Extension.Remove(0, 1)

        ElseIf targetFileExt.StartsWith("."c) Then
            targetFileExt = targetFileExt.Remove(0, 1)

        End If

        sourceFile.MoveTo(IO.Path.Combine(sourceFile.Directory.FullName,
                                     String.Format("{0}.{1}", targetFileName, targetFileExt)))

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw

    End Try

End Sub
```