# I need to change the extension of all the files in folder where extention is '.TXT' to '.DAT' using SSIS VB script task

Tags: ssis

I have come across the requirement where I have multiple files in Folder with different extentions. I need to change the extension only for those files who has the '.TXT' extension to '.DAT' file.
How can we achieve this using SSIS VB script task. I have already done this with File system task But I have asked to do this with only SSIS VB script task.

Could anyone share how can we do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggesting you know how to pass the folder path into the script task, you'd just need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584565/change-file-extension-on-multiple-files

Comment: @AlekseiLychev great example!

Comment: Thanks Aleksei Lychev,

I am able to solve this.